# calling rest api via vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call a rest based web service from Salesforce marketing cloud (which I can easily invoke using soap UI) from VBA on click of a button

however i am not getting response back as expected. i cannot debug on salesforce side as i dont have access to marketing cloud servers

```
Private Sub cmd_connect_Click()
    Dim clientSecret As String
    Dim clientId As String
    Dim TenentId As String
    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim blnAsync As Boolean
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim ReqBody As String

clientId = Worksheets("01Configure").txt_clientId.Value
clientSecret = Worksheets("01Configure").txt_clientSecret.Value
TenentId = Worksheets("01Configure").txt_TenentId.Value
strUrl = "https://" + TenentId + ".auth.marketingcloudapis.com" + "/v1/requestToken"

ReqBody = "{" & Chr(34) & "clientId" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "" + clientId + "" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "clientSecret" & Chr(34) & ":" & Chr(34) & "" + clientSecret + "" & Chr(34) & "}"
MsgBox ReqBody

Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
MsgBox strUrl
blnAsync = True

With objRequest
    .Open "POST", strUrl, blnAsync
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .Send ReqBody

    'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
    While objRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
    strResponse = .ResponseText
End With
MsgBox strResponse
End Sub
```

---

I expect response like:

```
{
       "accessToken": "Zp0JAhnyvWBBsS23e79Yp0CB",
       "expiresIn": 3479
    }
```

Comment: If you're not getting what you expect, what *are* you getting?

Comment: Why are you making an asynchronous request and then just looping until it comes back? You could make a synchronous request instead - i.e. `blnAsync = False`